I have a nullpointerexception problem in javafx, jdbc, postgresql, scene builder
I have a problem in fixing my java.lang.NullPointerException error.
Im able to connect to database, but I can't get data and put them into a Tableview. I always recieving: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.setCellValueFactory(javafx.util.Callback)" because "this.idMechanicy" is null. but I dont know what to do with this. I tried few things and nothing works. And of course I got my postgresql.jar, no problems on connect. And sorry for my bad english
Here is my code:
package org.example.projekt;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class HelloController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button exit;
    @FXML
    protected void exit(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Wyjście z programu");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @FXML
    private TableView<mechanicy> tableMechanicy;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<mechanicy,Integer> idMechanicy;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<mechanicy,String> nameMechanicy;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<mechanicy,String> surnameMechanicy;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<mechanicy,String> employmentMechanicy;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<mechanicy,String> specialisationMechanicy;

    ObservableList<mechanicy> listMechanicy = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        String sqlGetMechanicy = "select * from mechanicy";
        String urlDB = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/warsztat";
        String username = "postgres";
        String password = "student";

        {
            try {
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDB,username,password);
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                //resultGM - resultGetMechanicy
                ResultSet resultGM = st.executeQuery(sqlGetMechanicy);



                while (resultGM.next()) {

                    int id = resultGM.getInt("id");
                    String imie = resultGM.getString("imie");
                    String nazwisko = resultGM.getString("nazwisko");
                    String dataZatrudnienia = resultGM.getString("datazatrudnienia");
                    String specjalizacja = resultGM.getString("specjalizacja");

                    listMechanicy.add(new mechanicy(id,imie,nazwisko,dataZatrudnienia,specjalizacja));

                }

                idMechanicy.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<mechanicy,Integer>("id"));
                nameMechanicy.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<mechanicy,String>("name"));
                surnameMechanicy.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<mechanicy,String>("surname"));
                employmentMechanicy.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<mechanicy,String>("employmentdate"));
                specialisationMechanicy.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<mechanicy,String>("specialisation"));

                tableMechanicy.setItems(listMechanicy);



            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private Stage stage;
    @FXML
    private Scene scene;
    @FXML
    private Parent root;

    @FXML
    protected void goToCars(ActionEvent e) throws IOException
    {
    }

    @FXML
    protected void goToMechanics(ActionEvent e) throws IOException
    {
    }

    @FXML
    protected void goToMain(ActionEvent e) throws IOException
    {
    }

}

Mechanicy class:
package org.example.projekt;

public class mechanicy {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String employmentdate;
    private String specialisation;

    public mechanicy(int id, String name, String surname, String employmentdate, String specialisation) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.employmentdate = employmentdate;
        this.specialisation = specialisation;
    }

    public String getSpecialisation() {
        return specialisation;
    }

    public String getEmploymentdate() {
        return employmentdate;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public void setEmploymentdate(String employmentdate) {
        this.employmentdate = employmentdate;
    }

    public void setSpecialisation(String specialisation) {
        this.specialisation = specialisation;
    }

}

It's Hello-View.fxml:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane fx:id="Main" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.example.projekt.HelloController">
   <top>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="492.0" text="NA CZYM CHCESZ DZIAŁAĆ" textAlignment="CENTER" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </top>
   <right>
      <Button fx:id="auta" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goToCars" prefHeight="278.0" prefWidth="271.0" text="SAMOCHODY" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
   </right>
   <bottom>
      <Button fx:id="exit" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#exit" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="543.0" text="WYJDŹ Z PROGRAMU" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font size="37.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
   </bottom>
   <center>
      <Button fx:id="mechanicy" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goToMechanics" prefHeight="278.0" prefWidth="271.0" text="MECHANICY" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
   </center>
</BorderPane>

And mechanicy.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.example.projekt.HelloController">
   <bottom>
      <TabPane prefHeight="346.0" prefWidth="600.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="Dodaj pracownika">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="314.0" prefWidth="600.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label layoutX="60.0" layoutY="71.0" text="Label" />
                     </children></AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab text="Edytuj pracownika">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button layoutX="220.0" layoutY="49.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                     </children></AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
            <Tab text="Usuń pracownika">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
               </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab text="Wyświetl pracownika">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <TableView fx:id="tableMechanicy" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="265.0" prefWidth="573.0">
                          <columns>
                            <TableColumn fx:id="idMechanicy" prefWidth="45.0" text="ID" />
                            <TableColumn fx:id="nameMechanicy" prefWidth="117.0" text="Imie" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="surnameMechanicy" prefWidth="112.0" text="Nazwisko" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="employmentMechanicy" prefWidth="148.0" text="Data zatrudnienia" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="specialisationMechanicy" minWidth="7.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Specjalizacja" />
                          </columns>
                        </TableView>
                     </children></AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab text="Wyszukaj pracownika">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
               </content>
            </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </bottom>
   <top>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goToMain" prefHeight="84.0" prefWidth="620.0" text="Powrót" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font size="40.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
   </top>
</BorderPane>

Errors:
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Kamil/IdeaProjects/projekt/target/classes/org/example/projekt/hello-view.fxml

    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2700)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2563)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
    at org.example.projekt/org.example.projekt.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:15)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.setCellValueFactory(javafx.util.Callback)" because "this.idMechanicy" is null
    at org.example.projekt/org.example.projekt.HelloController.initialize(HelloController.java:75)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2670)
    ... 12 more
Exception running application org.example.projekt.HelloApplication

I watch many tutorials from connecting with database and how to use Tableview, I wrote the same code only with my variables and names, but I have always the same error
Edit:
Ok, thanks you guys for help, but I solved it. I just created individual fxml and controller for "Wyświetl pracownika" tab from mechanicy.fxml and it works. I'm stupid sometimes :P

Post the complete stack trace, formatted as code, in the question. Trim the application down to a [mre].

Don't mark fields that have nothing to do with FXML (like stage, scene and root), @FXML.  Don't use the PropertyValueFactory.  Never reassign a field marked @FXML to a new value.  (those recommendations are likely not the cause of your issue).  Provide the requested [mcve] -> code that reproduces the issue with no change or addition.

The stack trace you posted says the error occurs in hello-view.fxml, but you said the FXML you posted is called mechanicy.fxml. Which is correct?

Sorry, I forgot to paste hello-view.fxml too.

Don't use the same controller class for different FXML files. There is no element with fx:id="idMechanicy" in hello-view.fxml, so of course the corresponding field in the controller that is created when you load hello-view.fxml is not initialized. Use a different controller class for each FXML.

The logic in your code works. What does not work is the following:

Your controller is named "HelloController".

Your view (fxml) is named "mechanicy.fxml".

Your stacktrace says "Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
/C:/Users/Kamil/IdeaProjects/projekt/target/classes/org/example/projekt/hello-view.fxml
".


So you have 3 files involved, but it should only be two.
Next steps:

Check which fxml file is loaded by the FXMLLoader.

Check which controller class is assigned in this fxml file.

Correct it. Every fxml file should have its own controller class.



I'm realy sorry, I forgot to paste hello-view.fxml too

Your mechanicy.fxml has assigned the controller HelloController. It should be MechanicyController or something like that. You need to Link it correctly or create it.
